# How to make my code thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Given a `Factory` class with static method to create instance for `SomeModel` class, it will run in multi-thread environment. This `Factory` has three methods:

1. start
2. stop
3. createSomeModel

and a `state` field which is in:

1. shutted
2. starting
3. starting_failed
4. started
5. shutting
6. shutting_failed

Here's the current design of the `Factory` class:

```
public class Factory {

    enum State{
        shutted, starting, starting_failed, started, shutting, shutting_failed
    }

    State state;

    public static void start(){
        // can only be invoked when state=shutted
    }

    public static void stop(){
        // can only be invoked when state=started
    }

    public static void restart(){
        stop();
        start();
    }

    public static SomeModel create(){
        // can only be invoked when state=started
    }
}
```

My requirement is: `create` method can only be invoked when `state==started` and `start` method can only be invoked when `state==shutted || state == shutting_failed`, and `stop` method can only be invoked when `state==started|| state == starting_failed`.

I know this is related to thread synchronization problem, but I am not confident about my threading knowledge. Please help me.

Comment: Use `synchronized` blocks.

Comment: Are you sure that the `Factory` needs to have `static` methods for this? It looks like you want to have a single instance of `Factory` through all your application and there's no need for clients to call `start` method.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yes, you are right, is that bad to use static methods? should I use the singleton pattern ?

Comment: It's not bad to have `static` methods but `start` is not meant to be `static`. You could make your `Factory` an enum and it will be a singleton and its initialization will be thread safe. Still, you should apply some techniques so the execution of the methods is thread safe. Since you don't provide the specific details about your methods, we could only state you should use `synchronized` blocks after validating the state of your `Factory` for the implementation of `start` and `stop` methods, and `create` method doesn't need any synchronization at all unless it modifies the state of `Factory`.

Comment: You will make use of an `if` to check the status, if the `status` is still an invalid status, then throw a `RuntimeException` stating that the `Factory` has not yet been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't syncrhonize create method, so this will not be a bottleneck. And while you are stopping doesn't let the executions of new creates.
The double check "if state == started" is neccesary to avoid race conditions.

Probably there are better solutions than using Thread.sleep for wait that all create model finish, but I don't see how to do easily.

Hope this can help you.

```
enum State{
    shutted, starting, starting_failed, started, shutting, shutting_failed
}

private Factory() {
    // singleton: no more than 1 instances allowed
}

public static Factory getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

private static final Factory instance = new Factory();
private final AtomicInteger threadsCreatingModel = new AtomicInteger();
private volatile State state;


public synchronized void start(){
    if(state != State.shutted) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can only be invoked when state=shutted");
    }
    state = State.starting;
    // TODO: task
}

public synchronized void stop() throws InterruptedException {
    if(state != State.started) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can only be invoked when state=started");
    }
    state = State.shutting;

    // wait all threads that are creating SomeModel
    while (threadsCreatingModel.intValue() > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    // TODO: task
}

public SomeModel create(){
    if(state == State.started) {
        threadsCreatingModel.incrementAndGet();
        if(state == State.started) {
            // TODO: task   
        }
        threadsCreatingModel.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Comment: but how about the 'create' method ? synchronize this method will cause a performance drawback.

Comment: I've changed the code in oder that create method doesn't need syncrhonize and in order that stop waits all create method finish.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not to use static methods at all.

In stead, create objects of `Factory` class and let all methods be `synchronized`.

```
public enum State{
    shutted, starting, starting_failed, started, shutting, shutting_failed;
}

public class Factory {
    private State state;

    public synchronized void start(){
        if(state != State.shutted) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can only be invoked when state=shutted");
        }
        // do task
    }

    public synchronized void stop(){
        if(state != State.started) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can only be invoked when state=started");
        }
        // do task
    }

    public synchronized void restart(){
        stop();
        start();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but how about the 'create' method ?  synchronize this method will cause a performance drawback.

Answer (score 0):

No need to Synchronised. Use volatile or AtomicReference for State.
I am giving sample example for using volatile. It is best to use with primitive types so had to add int value for different state. Though you can use ordinals of enum but this way its a bit clear. Otherwise you can use AtomicReference.

```
public class Factory {
    private static volatile int factoryState;

    public synchronized void updateFactoryState(State newState, State ... expectedStates){
        for (State state : expectedStates)
            if(factoryState == State.shutted.getStateVal()){
                factoryState = newState.getStateVal();
        }
    }

    public void start(){
        try{
            updateFactoryState(State.starting, State.shutted, State.shutting_failed);
            System.out.println("steps to start the factory");
            //someExpensiveStartupMethod();
        }catch (Exception e){
            updateFactoryState(State.starting_failed, State.starting);
        }
        updateFactoryState(State.started, State.starting);
    }

    public void stop(){
        try{
            updateFactoryState(State.shutting, State.started, State.starting_failed);
            System.out.println("steps to stop the factory");
            //someExpensiveStopFactoryMethod();
        }catch (Exception e){
            updateFactoryState(State.shutting_failed, State.shutting);
        }
        updateFactoryState(State.shutted, State.shutting);
    }

    public void restart(){
        stop();
        start();
    }
    public static SomeModel create(){
        if(factoryState == State.started.getStateVal()) {
            System.out.println("Create Model");
        }   else{
            throw new RuntimeException("Can not create Model.Factory not in started state.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    enum State{
        shutted(0), starting(1), starting_failed(2), started(3), shutting(4), shutting_failed(5);
        private final int stateVal;

        State(int i) {
            stateVal = i;
        }

        public int getStateVal() {
            return stateVal;
        }
    }

    class SomeModel {}
}
```

Comment: This implementation is broken, because start(), stop(), create() contain race conditions. In general, volatile is only applicable, if you want to read a shared value without changing it, or if you want to change a primitive value atomically and don't have to care for its current figure.

Comment: Kind request, please read about volatile once more. Highest level of thread safety comes from immutability. Neither you need any safety to read immutable variable (like volatile or any) nor volatile gives you atomic operation on all primitive types. Again please revisit volatile.

Comment: The problem in that code: operation a) `if(factoryState==...)`; operation b) `factoryState=nextState` . If your thread is paused after a), but before b), the factoryState could receive an unexpected value before your thread continues its work. That's a race condition.

Comment: Agree with race condition :) but still not agree with other part of statement and stand by above comment.